# How do I resume the rotation where it last rotates when it got pause?

Tags: unity, c#

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    float Speed = 125f;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void ChangeDirection()
    {
        Speed = -Speed;
    }

    public void PauseMovement() <---- Pointer Down
    {
        Speed = 0f;
    }

    public void Boost()
    {
        Speed = 330f * Mathf.Sign(Speed);
    }

    public void NormalSpeed()   <----- Pointer Up
    {
        Speed = 125f * Mathf.Sign(Speed);
    }

}
```

I press a button on a trigger event as pointer down, my player stops moving and when i release the button, it resumes as per normal. This works but not as how i intended, when i want my player to resume, i want it to resume the direction it last went. Like if it rotates to the left, it will continue on the left. Right now, it last rotates on the left, it continues on the right. Please advice?

Comment: How about instead of setting speed to 0, you introduce a pause bool. That way you can either add a condition in your `FixedUpdate` to only Rotate when you are not paused or multiply it in your rotate function (0 for paused, 1 for not paused).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will define a bool:

```cs
private bool IsClockwise; // set it to true or false depending on your need
```

And then making the `Speed` variable non-negative:

```cs
    float Speed = 125f;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void ChangeDirection()
    {
        // We don't change the value of Speed here!
    }

    public void PauseMovement() <---- Pointer Down
    {
        Speed = 0f;
    }

    public void Boost()
    {
        Speed = 330f;
    }

    public void NormalSpeed()   <----- Pointer Up
    {
        Speed = 125f;
    }
```

And finally, let's define the new `ChangeDirection` method:

```
public void ChangeDirection()
{
    IsClockwise = !IsClockwise;
}
```

But it won't affect anything before we tweak the rotation part:

```cs
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (IsClockwise)
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    else
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Note that as you want to do this in `FixedUpdate`, you will need to use `fixedDeltaTime` instead of `deltaTime` ([see Unity's documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html))

Comment: You do not need to use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` just because it is `FixedUpdate()`. `Time.deltaTime` automatically uses `fixedDeltaTime` if called from `FixedUpdate()`. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Comment: @Zibelas thanks, I didn't know that. Though I think writing `fixedDeltaTime` is more clear (just a personal preference)

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @ShihsShihis If this answer helped you fix the issue, please consider marking it as "accepted".